# Simple IEnumerable class definition

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I saw an answer to my question on this forum but I've been looking for an hour today and I cant find it anymore.
I need to create a simple class with only 2 properties that will follow `IEnumerable` interface with `yield return` in enumerator that would return each of my 2 properties. I've done it before but I can't find my code nor StackOverflow post that I followed.
Please help...

Comment: You could always try actually learning about how [yield return works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ibrary/9k7k7cf0). Writing the code should take less time than searching for it.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert  - that's deep but I do know how yield return works - I spent time to learn about it. But I guess you never experience palm face or brain freeze, do you. In this case I just couldn't remember how to fulfill interface promise....

Comment: No offense was intended. But no, I have indeed never spent an hour looking for a particular piece of code, and I hope I'll never need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (or I not understand your question?)

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<object>
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }

    public int SecondProperty { get; set; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return FirstProperty;
        yield return SecondProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I was looking for.